# Efficiently find indices of maxima of a list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

**Edit**: I must not have worded it clearly enough, but I'm looking for a function *like* the one below,  but not exactly it.

Given a list, I wanted to be able to find the index of the largest element in the list
(So, `list !! (indexOfMaximum list) == maximum list`)
I wrote some code that seems pretty efficient, although I feel I'm reinventing the wheel somewhere.

```
indexOfMaximum :: (Ord n, Num n) => [n] -> Int
indexOfMaximum list =
   let indexOfMaximum' :: (Ord n, Num n) => [n] -> Int -> n -> Int -> Int
       indexOfMaximum' list' currIndex highestVal highestIndex
          | null list'                = highestIndex
          | (head list') > highestVal = 
               indexOfMaximum' (tail list') (1 + currIndex) (head list') currIndex
          | otherwise                 = 
               indexOfMaximum' (tail list') (1 + currIndex) highestVal highestIndex
   in indexOfMaximum' list 0 0 0
```

Now I want to return a list of the indices of the largest n numbers in the list.

My only solution is to store the top n elements in a list and replace `(head list') > highestVal` with a comparison across the n-largest-so-far list.

It feels like there has to be a more efficient way than to do this, and I also feel I'm making insufficient use of Prelude and Data.List. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution associates each element with its index, sorts the list, so the smallest element is first, reverses it so the largest element is first, takes the first n elements, and then extracts the index.

```
maxn n xs = map snd . take n . reverse . sort $ zip xs [0..]
```

Comment: I had thought of something like this, but damn that sounds a lot more efficient now that you say it. Thanks.

Comment: however, this takes at least O(N log N), where N is the length of the list

Comment: Indeed.  I think if we used `sortBy (flip compare)`, the laziness of the sort function would kick in to make this solution basically `O(N)` if only `O(1)` of the top elements are demanded.

Comment: Doh!  I was wondering how best to invert compare. I was hung up on inverting the result, when flipping the arguments does the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way finds the last index of a maximum element,

```
maxIndex list = snd . maximum $ zip list [0 .. ]
```

If you want the first index,

```
maxIndex list = snd . maximumBy cmp $ zip list [0 .. ]
  where
    cmp (v,i) (w,j) = case compare v w of
                        EQ -> compare j i
                        ne -> ne
```

The downside is that `maximum` and `maximumBy` are too lazy, so these may build large thunks. To avoid that, either use a manual recursion (like you did, but some strictness annotations may be necessary) or use a strict left fold *with a strict accumulator type*, tuples are not good for that because `foldl'` only evaluates to weak head normal form, that is to the outermost constructor here, and thus you build thunks in the tuple components.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a simple way would be to use `maximum` to find the largest element and then use `findIndices` to find each occurrence of it. Something like:

```
largestIndices :: Ord a => [a] -> [Int]
largestIndices ls = findIndices (== maximum ls) ls
```

However, this is not perfect because `maximum` is a partial function and will barf horribly if given an empty list. You can easily avoid this by adding a `[]` case:

```
largestIndices :: Ord a => [a] -> [Int]
largestIndices [] = []
largestIndices ls = findIndices (== maximum ls) ls
```

The real trick to this answer is how I figured it out. I didn't even know about `findIndices` before now! However, GHCi has a neat command called `:browse`.

```
Prelude> :browse Data.List
```

This lists every single function exported by `Data.List`. Using this, I just search first for `maximum` and then for `index` to see what the options were. And, right by `findIndex`, there was `findIndecies`, which was perfect.

Finally, I would not worry about efficiency unless you actually see that code is running slowly. GHC can--and does--perform some very aggressive optimizations because the language is pure and it can get away with it. So the only time you need to worry about performance is when--after compiling with -O2--you see that it's a problem.

EDIT: If you want to find the `n` top elements' indices, here's an easy idea: sort the list in descending order, grab the first `n` unique elements, get their indices with `elemIndices` and take the first `n` indices from that. I hope this is relatively clear.

Here's a quick version of my idea:

```
nLargestInices n ls = take n $ concatMap (`elemIndices` ls) nums
  where nums = take n . reverse . nub $ sort ls
```

Comment: Ooh, nice finds with `:browse` and `findIndices`! I think you misunderstood a little, though: I want to find indices of the n largest elements, *which may not be equal*. Now that you've pointed out `findIndices`, I'm trying to bake up something with `elemIndices`, but I'm still having trouble.

Comment: Oh. I thought you wanted to find all the indices of the largest elements. My bad.

Comment: Still +1 for usefulness, definitely.